# Woocommerce - Related products for entire category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add some related products or Up-Sells for an entire category, instead of adding them to each product in that category individually. Is this possible and if so how do I go about doing this?

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 0):

1st add custom field to the category that will be used for upsells. I use relationship field of advanced custom fields plugin for such things. Once this is done add filter in themes functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_upsell_ids', 'category_upsells', 10, 2 );
function category_upsells($upsell_ids, $product) {
    // get the category of the product and from the category get the product ids from your custom theme
    // set $upsell_ids to your product ids
    return $upsell_ids;
}
```